# How to install Windows Service on Docker container with server core

Tags: docker, windows-services, server-core

I am trying to install a windows service in a docker container with server core, but when I try to start my service, it returns the following error.

[Issue Docker ServerCore Start Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmwTs.png)

Already probe:
- Start powershell as administrator.
- Use cmd with sc start "service"

Is it possible to do this in Server Core?